# How to find/get two separated regions which have the same pixel values in an image?

Tags: python, scipy

I have an array

```
a=array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
         [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

When I did `scipy.ndimage.find_objects(a)`, I got

```
[(slice(0, 5, None), slice(0, 5, None))]
```

which seemed taking a bounding box a[0:5, 0:5].

What I want to achieve is two separated regions as result since these ones are from two separated regions. I would like to get result something like

```
[(slice(0, 3, None), slice(0, 2, None)), (slice(4, 5, None), slice(4, 5, None))]
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs of scipy.ndimage:

> Find objects in a labeled array.
>
> Parameters
>
> ```
> input ndarray of ints
>
>     Array containing objects defined by different labels.
>     Labels with value 0 are ignored.
> ```

The important part here is the **different labels**.

If you change your array to

```py
a=array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
         [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

you will get `[(slice(0, 2, None), slice(0, 3, None)), (slice(4, 5, None), slice(4, 5, None))]` that is the expected result. I don't know if you can do this or not in the source, otherwise can you please clarify the question?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will assign each region in your matrix a unique integer, which you can then pipe into scipy.ndimage.find_objects. Perhaps a little redundant, but it should work.

```
from skimage.segmentation import flood, flood_fill

a = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

temp = a
out = np.zeros(a.shape)
count = 1
# Iterate through each cell in the grid
for x, y in np.ndindex(a.shape):
    # Identify regions centered at (or connected to) non-zero values
    if temp[x][y]!=0:
        # Replace all values in this region with a unique number
        # Connectivity of 1 means diagonal connections do not count
        # Tolerance of 0 means adjacent cells in a region must be exactly equal
        out += count*flood(a, (x,y), connectivity=1, tolerance=0)
        # Zero out all values in this region to prevent duplicate efforts
        temp = flood_fill(temp, (x,y), 0, connectivity=1, tolerance=0)
        count += 1
        
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[[1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```